# Strict value check of indexed types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, index-signature

I want to know if its possible to have a indexed type, where if a key is defined, the object is defined as well, but the key itself is not necessarily set. Example:

```
type Car = { model: string };
type Cars = { [id: string]: Car};
const cars: Cars = {};
const aCar = cars["a"];
console.log(aCar.model);
// no errors, but is wrong
const carModels = Object.values(cars).map(car => car.model);
// no errors, is correct
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgQwE4wLwwN4wLYHsAmUANgFwwDOISAlgHYDmMAvgNyiSyJLlqYwDa1fGUo0GAXTJdWwAMa5alGLOTkpq3hhnzFIGAi68V3fgCIEp8Wx3lcRKADoiuegAoDyB3kJEAlGwB6AJhaXBgoJCRcbgAaGAAjAFc9ah4AdyiGOQUlYwBZAmIedAB5eIArKFkQBwA3BCJEqHJXY3JfLwQIVuQ0AD5lT29if2AgkLCIqNiYVOVopCqQIA)

```
type Car = { model: string };
type Cars = { [id: string]: Car | undefined};
const cars: Cars = {};
const aCar = cars["a"]; // basically, I want this to be potentially undefined
console.log(aCar.model);
// "aCar" is possibly undefined, correct error
const carModels = Object.values(cars).map(car => car.model);
// "car" is possibly undefined, bad error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJygXigbygWwPYBMIA2AXFAM7AICWAdgOZQC+A3AFCiSyKkrpQDalXCXJU6AXRLwkAHygBXavgBmNCLmYsAxtmrkomrpK480G7buBQ4UngYSk+AIjiOxrc6WwEIAOgLZaAAprRB8cfAIASlYAehioZylHKEpuMGxSUkoAIwIQeUUIFWo1ABp9bAQECE1LCCrKrR09OwBZPEJuVAB5bIArGuAfADc4AjkIUkC7UkiwuDBpxBQAPn1Q8MJoljiEu2TUqHTMnLyC5VVccuy4XCh6hEqgA)

The problem is that `Object.values` will also take into account the optionality of the `Cars` object values.

I think the `Map` object would work and be typed the way I want to, but there's syntax overhead of using setters and getters.

This might be more of a language request, but as an added bonus, it would be amazing if the type would be inferred to be not optionally undefined in cases like this:

```
if ("foo" in cars) {
  console.log(cars["foo"])
}
```

Comment: Re: "language request" this you should do on the [TypeScript repo itself](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript). Although I think it was already proposed as this is a trade-off of the control-flow analysis: the compiler simply does not know that when you index by property you already type guarded before it should not be optional

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is possible with the [noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) flag (available since Typescript 4.1).